# How to align two responsive divs vertically without using flexbox?

Tags: css, responsive-design, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to use two divs side by side with responsive design. Left div contains an image which changes with page size. Right div contains a menu which will not change. When the page gets to a certain size (too small), the menu is supposed to under the image and stay in the middle).

But it also needs to be vertically aligned in the middle of the left div.

Should be centered vertically on bigger screens:

[image: need to center]

It works correctly on smaller screens currently:

[image: works correctly on mobile]

Here's my HTML:

```
<div id="container">
        <div id="content">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="column" style="background-color:#aaa;">
                <img class="header-img" sr="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png"/>
          </div>
          <div class="column" style="background-color:#bbb;">
            <table style="width:100%">
              <tr>
                <td>Menu</td>
                <td>Menu</td> 
                <td>Menu</td>
                <td>Menu</td>
              </tr>
              </table>
              <table style="width:100%">
              <tr>
                <td>Menu</td>
                <td>Menu</td> 
                <td>Menu</td>
                <td>Menu</td>
                <td>Menu</td>
              </tr>
            </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's my CSS:

```
    #content {
        max-width: 1500px;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        background-color:red;
    }

    * {box-sizing: border-box;}

    body { 
      margin: 0;
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }

    /* Create two equal columns that floats next to each other */
    .column {
      float: left;
      width: 50%;
      padding: 10px;
    }

    /* Clear floats after the columns */
    .row:after {
      content: "";
      display: table;
      clear: both;
    }

    /* Responsive layout - makes the two columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */
    @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
      .column {
        width: 100%;
      }
    }

    .header-img {
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 500px;
    }

    td {
        text-align: center;
    }
```

I tried everything, but all the other regular alignment methods break everything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `display:table` and `display:table-cell`.

```
.row{
  display:table;
  width:100%;
}

.column {
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .column {
    width: 100%;
    display:block;
  }
}
```

`vertical-align:middle` keeps everything vertically aligned in the middle too.

Here's a [CODE PEN](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mvBObo) so you can see

Answer (score 0):

Similar answer as jleggio, but here the red background remains according to the image in the question as well.

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box;}

body { 
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#container {
 display: table;
 width: 100%;
}

#content {
 max-width: 1500px;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 background-color: red;
}

.cell {
 width: 50%;
 display: table-cell;
 vertical-align: middle;
}


@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
 .cell {
     width: 100%;
  display: block;
 }
}

.header-img {
 width: 100%;
 max-width: 500px;
}

td {
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
 <div id="content">
  <div class="cell" style="background-color: #aaa;">
   <img class="header-img" src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png"/>
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
   <div style="background-color: #bbb;">
       <table style="width:100%">
     <tr>
      <td>Menu</td>
      <td>Menu</td> 
      <td>Menu</td>
      <td>Menu</td>
     </tr>
    </table>
    <table style="width:100%">
     <tr>
      <td>Menu</td>
      <td>Menu</td> 
      <td>Menu</td>
      <td>Menu</td>
      <td>Menu</td>
     </tr>
       </table>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```